# Issue with http toolkit and proxifier integration - Seeking Assistance

Tags: proxy, http-proxy, http-toolkit

I hope this message finds you well. I am currently facing an issue with integrating HTTP Toolkit and Proxifier for traffic interception and IP address change, respectively. I would appreciate any guidance or assistance you can provide to help me resolve this matter.

Here is a brief description of the problem:

I am using HTTP Toolkit to intercept traffic, and the program utilizes localhost and a random port for this purpose, which has been working perfectly fine. Simultaneously, I am running Proxifier to change my IP address. However, when I add a rule to force localhost to use the Proxifier proxy, it seems to be causing some issues, and the expected behavior is not being achieved.

To provide more context, the steps I am taking are as follows:

Running HTTP Toolkit for traffic interception on localhost with a random port.
Simultaneously running Proxifier to change my IP address.
Adding a rule in Proxifier to force localhost to use the Proxifier proxy.
Unfortunately, despite following these steps, the integration does not seem to be working as expected. I have reviewed the configurations and settings multiple times but have not been able to identify the root cause of the problem.

If anyone in the community has experience with this setup or can provide insights into potential solutions, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Additionally, if you need more information or specific details about my configuration, please let me know, and I will be happy to provide them.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance. I look forward to your valuable input.

Best regards,
Scool

Comment: Can you explain in _much_ more detail what "the integration does not seem to be working as expected" means? Please share screenshots of errors and details of what you expect to be happening. Can you also explain what you're trying to do more generally? Where is the HTTP traffic coming from and where is it going?

Comment: I have successfully utilized the HTTP Toolkit, and after subscribing to its pro version, I encountered an issue with the tool using the system's IP address. Although I attempted to configure a proxy through the settings, I encountered a setback as the proxy I use requires authentication, and the toolkit lacks the option for proxy authentication.

Comment: In an effort to work around this limitation, I experimented with Proxifier to change the IP by forcing the localhost to use the Proxifier proxy. Unfortunately, this resulted in pages failing to load, accompanied by errors. I am now seeking a solution to either directly integrate proxies into the HTTP Toolkit or find an alternative tool that allows IP changes while maintaining the functionality of the HTTP Toolkit.

Comment: HTTP Toolkit does support proxy authentication, you just need to include the parameters in the proxy URL like "username:password@server". This is a common proxy URL format. That will solve your problem better than attempting to chain together proxifier with HTTP Toolkit.